# Removing value from heap: why siftup and siftdown need to be called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap

```py
    def remove(self, heap, element):
        ind = heap.index(element)
        heap[ind] = heap[-1]
        del heap[-1]

        if ind < len(heap):
            heapq._siftup(heap, ind)
            heapq._siftdown(heap, 0, ind)
```

I have a heap from which an element needs to be removed. This is my understanding of the above code:

- The variable `ind` gets the index of that element in the heap array.
- `heap[ind] = heap[-1]` puts that element at the top
- `del heap[-1]` deletes that element.

But what is the rest of the code doing?

Why would `ind` be less than the length of the heap? I have no idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `heap[ind] = heap[-1]` puts that element at the top

No, it actually copies the last element at the index `ind` where `element` was found, so that `element` is actually deleted (by overwriting it).

> Why would `ind` be less than length of heap?

Assuming that `element` actually occurs in the heap, `ind` can be anything between 0 and `len(heap)`. Because the size of the heap is reduced by doing `delete heap[-1]`, `ind` could even be equal to `len(heap)`, considering the length *after* that deletion.

So we can have two possibilities; either:

- `ind == len(heap)`: this happens when the `element` was found at the very end of the heap: a boundary case. By the `delete heap[-1]` the length of the heap was reduced so that we have this equality. In this case there is nothing more to do, as `delete heap[-1]` deleted the element that had to be deleted.
- `ind < len(heap)`: this is the more generic case. In this case we did *not* delete the `element`, but another element. That element was copied to index `ind`, and so we actually deleted `element`... by overwriting it. The only thing that remains to do is to restore the heap property, which ensures that a value is not less than its parent and not greater than either of its children.

  This is why we need to call a sift function. The value that moved to index `ind` could happen to be in violation of the heap property.

> But what is the code below doing?

Some examples may clarify what is happening

### Example 1

Let's say we have this (min) heap: [1, 2, 3] which is this tree:

```
             1
            / \
           2   3
```

... and we call this function to delete 1, then this is what happens:

1. We identify that 1 occurs at index 0 (`ind`)
2. The value 3 is copied to index 0, so the heap temporarily has a duplicate entry: [3, 2, 3]
3. The last entry is removed, so we get [3, 2], which is this tree:

   ```
             3
            /
           2
   ```
4. As this tree violates the heap property, we call `heapq._siftdown`. That method will move the value 3 *down* until it is at a place where the heap property is restored. This will result in the heap [2, 3]:

   ```
               2
              /
             3
   ```

### Example 2

Let's say we have this (min) heap: [1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3] which is this tree:

```
              _1_
            /     \
           5       2
          / \     /
         6   7   3
```

... and we call this function to delete 6, then this is what happens:

1. We identify that 6 occurs at index 3 (`ind`)
2. The value 3 is copied to index 3, so the heap temporarily has a duplicate entry: [1, 5, 2, 3, 7, 3]
3. The last entry is removed, so we get [1, 5, 2, 3, 7], which is this tree:

   ```
              _1_
            /     \
           5       2
          / \
         3   7
   ```
4. As this tree violates the heap property, we call `heapq._siftup`. That method will move the value 3 *up* until it is at a place where the heap property is restored. This will result in the heap [1, 3, 2, 5, 7]:

   ```
              _1_
            /     \
           3       2
          / \
         5   7
   ```

So in example 1 we see a case where a sift-down was necessary, while in example 2 a sift-up was needed. This is the reason why *both* sift methods are called: this way it is sure that the moved value will be brought at a position where it obeys the heap property. Note that at most one of the two method calls will actually *move* the element, while the other call is harmless.

Comment: This is an incredible answer @trincot thank you!